# Colorbox and ajax youtube - not working together?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, youtube, colorbox

I'm using ajax to get and create a list with youtube videos from specific user and jquery.colorbox as a jQuery lightbox.

I can't make them to work together :(
Can someone tell me how to fix, please.

DEMO: http://dev.template-tuners.com/a/youtube.html

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with what you've done:  First, remove the class cboxElement from your code.  Second, don't query the document for all '.youtube' links on each iteration in $.each, it is very inefficient.  Third, you can't query the document for '.youtube' if you haven't appended that HTML to the document yet.

Move these lines:

```
$(".youtube").colorbox({
    iframe:true, 
    innerWidth:640, 
    innerHeight:360,
});
```

To be the very statement thing in your show_my_videos function.